# A way to check for undefined null and 0

Tags: javascript

I am dealing with the old codebase again and was just curious, can this line be left so or can be improved?

`if (data.COUNTRY === undefined || data.COUNTRY === null || data.COUNTRY.length === 0) {}`

Comment: `data.COUNTRY == null || data.COUNTRY.length === 0`

Comment: One thing is that `data.COUNTRY == null` does exactly the same thing as comparing with `===` to both `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: If, if it exists, it won't be falsey, then yes. Otherwise, not really, though you could use `.includes` if you wanted to be DRY

Comment: try `if(data.country)`

Comment: That line is fine. It is short and very clear. If you absolutely want to change it, you could use the suggestion of Felix or something like `!data.COUNTRY && typeof data.COUNTRY !== 'number'`. I guess it depends on the exact context to decide what to use. Note that just using `!data.COUNTRY` changes the behaviour of the code. For example, `0` is falsy but your code does not include it in your condition.

Comment: For a more declarative, just 
`if(!Boolean(data.COUNTRY) || !Boolean(data.COUNTRY.length)) { ... }`